# Looping video using MPMoviePlayerController somewhere between startTime and endTime of the Video

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

Suppose the video duration is 50 seconds. In need to loop part of the video between 10th sec to 20th sec. 
Very first time when I play the video it works fine. But for 2nd iteration onwards the video plays from the start (i.e from 0th second rather than 10th second).
Following is my code:

```
    self.moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:currentVideoURL];
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: movieView.bounds];
    [self.moviePlayer.view setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [self.moviePlayer setInitialPlaybackTime:10.0];
    [self.moviePlayer setEndPlaybackTime:20.0];
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer];

    [self.movieView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];



- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note {

   if (note.object == self.moviePlayer) {
    NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {

     //   [self.moviePlayer setInitialPlaybackTime:10.0];
     //   [self.moviePlayer setEndPlaybackTime:20.0];
        [self.moviePlayer play];
    }
  }
}
```

Also I tried to reset the `InitialPlaybackTime` and `EndPlaybackTime` in by `moviePlayerDidFinish` Method, but didn't worked.

Depending on the requirement I only need to loop only particular part of the video.
Please help me.. Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you found any solution? Or you decided to use simple timers?

Comment: @IgorPalaguta I didn't found solution for this. Eventually I used UIWebview to render my video file using html video tag and was able to control it using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

set the property repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne of MPMoviePlayerController self.moviePlayer.

```
self.moviePlayer repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

See Example

```
-(void)playMovie:(id)sender
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"MOV"]];

_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
_moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 3.0;
_moviePlayer.endPlaybackTime = 5.0;
_moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

}